# Is there any way to aggregate two collection within range of specific field's value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am totally new to MongoDB, I want to aggregate two collections using the `$lookup` function.
Is there any ways to compare a Field from Collection A to a field from collection B within range of `x`?

For example:

Collection A's time(variable named timestamp in below code) info is 12:00:00

Collection B's time(variable named timestamp in below code) info is 12:01:00

I want to aggregate documents within a range of 1 sec.

Here is my current code sample:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://ipaddress/tms";

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("tms");
    dbo.collection('transaction_logs').aggregate([
        {
            $lookup:
                {
                    from: 'transactionLogs',
                    localField: 'deviceSn' && 'deviceName' && 'timestamp',
                    foreignField: 'deviceSn' && 'deviceName' && 'timestamp',
                    as: 'transactionLogs_docs'
                }
        },
        { $out: "integrated_transaction_logs" }
    ]).toArray(function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mongo version 3.6+ you can use the ["new"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) `$lookup` version which allows you to use a customised pipeline.

The strategy will be to calculate the difference between two dates by subtracting them, if the absolute value of that difference is less than 1000 (a second in milliseconds) then we will match the document.

Mind you `$lookup` is a very expensive stage as it is, and this usage of it will not perform well as you for each document in `collection_one` you have to scan and calculate the different with each document in `collection_two`.

I created my own sample collections as you didn't provide any:

```
  "collection": [
    {
      id: 1,
      date: ISODate("2020-09-24T02:24:45.631Z"),
      
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      date: ISODate("2020-09-24T04:24:45.632Z"),
      
    }
  ],
  "collection_two": [
    {
      id: 1,
      colTwoDate: ISODate("2020-09-24T02:24:46.431Z"),
      
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      colTwoDate: ISODate("2020-09-24T02:24:44.832Z"),
      
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      colTwoDate: ISODate("2020-09-24T02:30:00.000Z"),
      
    }
  ]
```

Pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection_two",
      "let": {
        "colOneDate": "$date"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $lte: [
                {
                  $abs: {
                    "$subtract": [
                      "$$colOneDate",
                      "$colTwoDate"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                1000
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "matched"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uFPRPzwv_Ja)